# sort products for specific category page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I want to sort products for specific book category page woocommerce but i am unable to do that
below is the code i have applied but not worked for me

/*

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby','custom_catalog_ordering_args_func',220, 1);

   function custom_catalog_ordering_args_func($sortby)
   {
     $product_category = 'book'; // <== HERE define product category slug 

    if (! is_product_category($product_category)) {
        return;
    }else{
        return 'date';
    }
   
}
```

*/

Comment: So you want to sort products by date for the book category and use the default for every other?

Comment: yes you r right

Comment: let me know the way even if possible to do this by  write hard code in woocommerce file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby` action hook. check the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'change_catalog_orderby_for_category' );
function change_catalog_orderby_for_category( $sort_by ) {
    if( is_product_category('book') ) { 
        return 'date';
    }
    return $sort_by;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'sort_by_date', 10, 1);
function sort_by_date($sortby){

    if (! is_product_category('book')) {
        return 'date';
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: really? because you are using else and I dont use it. Did you try my version?

Comment: i want to have product in date order when  is_product_category('book') so i think still your code is not proper but let me correct an try

Comment: what is not proper on my code? When is book return date else return